# Error Compiling node.js v0.10.31 for armv7

Tags: javascript, node.js, compiler-errors, raspberry-pi

When trying to compile Node.js v0.10.31 (and v0.10.30) on Ubuntu 14.04 for use on Raspberry pi (running ARM). I'm using the following compiler flags:

```
export AR=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
export CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
export LINK=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
```

However I get the following error:

```
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/node/out'
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -pthread -rdynamic -Wl,--whole-archive /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/libopenssl.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,--whole-archive /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/deps/v8/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -pthread  -o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/node -Wl,--start-group /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/fs_event_wrap.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/cares_wrap.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/handle_wrap.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/node.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/node_buffer.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/node_constants.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/node_extensions.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/node_file.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/node_http_parser.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/node_javascript.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/node_main.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/node_os.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/node_script.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/node_stat_watcher.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/node_string.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/node_zlib.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/pipe_wrap.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/signal_wrap.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/string_bytes.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/stream_wrap.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/slab_allocator.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/tcp_wrap.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/timer_wrap.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/tty_wrap.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/process_wrap.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/v8_typed_array.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/udp_wrap.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/node_crypto.o /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/deps/openssl/libopenssl.a /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/deps/zlib/libchrome_zlib.a /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/deps/http_parser/libhttp_parser.a /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/deps/cares/libcares.a /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/deps/uv/libuv.a /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/deps/v8/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a /home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/obj.target/deps/v8/tools/gyp/libv8_nosnapshot.a -Wl,--end-group -lm -ldl -lrt
/home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/libopenssl.a(armcap.o): In function `OPENSSL_cpuid_setup':
armcap.c:(.text.startup+0x0): multiple definition of `OPENSSL_cpuid_setup'
/home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/libopenssl.a(cryptlib.o):cryptlib.c:(.text+0x360): first defined here
/home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/libopenssl.a(armcap.o): In function `OPENSSL_rdtsc':
armcap.c:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `_armv7_tick'
/home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/libopenssl.a(armcap.o): In function `OPENSSL_cpuid_setup':
armcap.c:(.text.startup+0xe0): undefined reference to `_armv7_tick'
armcap.c:(.text.startup+0x10c): undefined reference to `_armv7_neon_probe'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [/home/ubuntu/node/out/Release/node] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/node/out'
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

Any ideas how to solve this error? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently installed Node on a Raspberry Pi (do not use apt-get, even on Raspbian. If you can move to Raspbian, as far as I know Ubuntu doesn't like ARM). Try this:

```
$ cd /home/pi/node/ #or any directory you want
$ wget http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_latest_armhf.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i node_latest_armhf.deb
```

If you try to open the REPL (`$ node`) and this gives you an error, it's probably because it can't find the executable find. In that case this following command made it work for me:

```
$ hash -r
```

Comment: Awesome, they have the latest node.js v0.10.31 precompiled!

Comment: If this solution is good enough please mark it as correct.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to install node.js on RPi.

[Install Node on the Raspberry Pi in 5 minutes](http://joshondesign.com/2013/10/23/noderpi)

The problem I found was that the latest node.js distribution (v0.10.31) did not include the precompiled version for the RPi. I had to go the last distribution that contained the precompiled node.js for the RPi (v0.10.28).  Here is the link to the distribution repository:

http://nodejs.org/dist/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the instruction. I will include more info in future answers.