# node.js hang on ARM7 based ubuntu 12.04

Tags: node.js

When running nodejs (ver v0.10.33) on arm7 based ubuntu, it hangs. I had to ctrl-c after a few minutes.

```
$node te.js
```

according to "top" command, the node process is taking 100% of CPU.

```
==== te.js ====
console.log("hi you");
```

This is my OS and kernel

```
$ more /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS \n \l
$uname -a
Linux LINUXIUMONE 3.0.36+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Feb 15 20:54:36 EST 2014 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

The CPU is ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v7l) with quad cores, 1.6GHz, BogoMIPS    : 3214.95

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install node?

Comment: I installed node by `sudo apt-get install nodejs`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540180/error-compiling-node-js-v0-10-31-for-armv7) helps! I uninstalled and reinstalled it (steps reproduced here for the convenience of readers) and worked great.

```
$ wget http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_latest_armhf.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i node_latest_armhf.deb
```